# Selenium Python. How to replace "_blank" from url

Tags: python, selenium, replace, hyperlink, tags

Help me please. I parse page with selenium. Next step i need to click url. But url have target _blank and it open in new tab. As i know, i can replace _blank to "". But my code is not work.

```html
firefoxProfile = FirefoxProfile()
firefoxProfile.set_preference('permissions.default.stylesheet', 2)  # 
firefoxProfile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)  # 
firefoxProfile.set_preference("dom.popup_maximum", 0)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefoxProfile)

gourl = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("html body div.container.container_n div#top.wrapper section.main section.content-right div.catalog-content div.catalog-col div.catalog-col-middle h2 a.nameofgood")
    browser.execute_script("gourl.getElementById('nameofgood').target = '';")
    webdriver.ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(gourl).click(gourl).perform()
    
my parsing code is:
<h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="nameofgood" href="/cat/nn/4353419/" numberinsidecatalog="1">Кабель силовой АПвКаВ 1х400мк/50-20</a></h2>
```

my html code:

### good position

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the attribute value, you could do it like this :

```
element =  browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a.nameofgood")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('target','set the value of target here')", element)
```

instead (in case you do not wanna use the above method), you can switch also to new tab in Selenium like this :

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("xpath of anchro tag").click()
handles = browser.window_handles
browser.switch_to.window(handles[1])
```

Comment: @RomanLegasov : Can we close this ticket now ? You have to accept it in order to close this ticket, once close it will be marked in green color for future readers. please feel free click on check mark which is right aside with voting buttons. I'd appreciate your time and response on this.